# Why does my variable not subtract in my batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Im making a batch file, basically a simple game.

I wrote two lines of code, one is:
`set /a hp=%hp%-%edmg%`

and the other is:
`set /a ehp=%ehp%-%dmg%`

And for some reason the first one works, and the second dosent. I tried changing the variable name, deleting the first command, placing them under different markers, but that didnt help. Is there a fix to that?

Comment: Looks like the `set` commands are inside a parenthesized code block? Either apply  [Delayed Expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as `set /a ehp=!ehp!-!dmg!` or take in mind that `SET /A` allows you to omit the `%`'s completely so use `set /a ehp=ehp-dmg`…

Answer (score 0):

You can also use subroutines and / or macro's if you want to have a little bit more fun with your coding

**Subroutine driven approach**

Advantage: Easier to do further modifications within code blocks / For Loops

Disadvantage: Slower

```
@echo off & Goto :Main

:math
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set "Var=!%~1!"
    Set /A "Var%2=%~3"
(
    Endlocal
    Set %1=%Var%
    Exit /B
)


:Main
    Set "@M=Call :math"
    Set Hp=40
    Set heal=30
    %@M% Hp - 20
    Echo(%Hp%
    %@M% Hp + heal
    Echo(%Hp%
    %@M% Hp / 3
    Echo(%Hp%
    %@M% Hp * 4
    Echo(%Hp%
    pause >nul
```

**Macro Approach**

Advantage: More efficient than calls to subroutines.

Disadvantage: Less intuitive to be able to build (Worth mastering though), process to access and further modifiy the variable within codeblocks is overcomplicated.

```
@Echo Off
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    (set LF=^


    %= Newline =%)
    Set ^"\n=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^"

    (Set "Operate=Endlocal ^& Set /A ""%%G%%H=%%I"""

    %= 'Tunnels' variable value, Allows Definition of Arithmetic within Macro =%)

    Set @M=for /L %%n in (1 1 2) do if %%n==2 (%\n%
    for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=, " %%G in ("!argv!") do (%\n%
    %Operate%%\n%
%=  Display value of variable. Not recommended, as Call reduces efficiency gain =%
    Call Echo(%%G: %%%%G%%%\n%
    ) %\n%
) ELSE setlocal enableDelayedExpansion ^& set argv=, 


%=  Facilitate modification of variables within codeblocks. =%
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM macro can be used to define as well as modify variables
REM output of macro can be redirected to nul (hidden) like so:
REM (%@M% hp + 50)>nul

    %@M% hp + 50
    (%@M% heal + 30)>nul
    %@M% hp - 30
    %@M% hp + 25
    %@M% hp * 3
    %@M% hp / 2
    %@M% hp + heal
    %@M% heal - 10
    %@M% hp + heal
%=  Demomonstates use of equation beyond the initial Operator. Spaces cannot be used. =%
%=  Increments variable by a random amount in the range of 10 to 20 =%
    For /L %%A in (1,1,50) do (%@M% hp + !random!%%10+10)>nul
    Echo(hp: %hp%
    For /L %%A in (1,1,50) do (%@M% hp - !random!%%10+10)

pause
```